# How to start new Git from scratch when old Git still there

Tags: bash, git, github

I want to create a new empty repository with git. I cannot find a simple solution online that explains this step.

This documentation states "git-init - Create an empty Git repository or reinitialize an existing one" but then doesn't say which options are needed to make it empty:
https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html

Is a `--bare` repository the same as an empty repository?

**Problem:**

I have two different projects with different repo's on github, but when I try to use Git (in Bash) after changing the directory to the new project, it keeps pushing with files from the old project.

I think the problem is that git is using the old repo files and thinks the new folder is just additional files perhaps? Basically I want to start from fresh. Can I just start from scratch on my new project with a new repo?

I have tried  `$ git init` in a new directory, but then it just says: "Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/user/new_project/.git/"

I tried: `$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:User/New_Project.git`
but that just updates where it pushes my new project to, and then includes old projects files.

Please help a noob trying to figure things out the hard way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `.git` folder:

```
rm -rf .git
```

Then create new git repository:

```
git init
git remote add origin <remote-URL>
git add .
git commit -m "new clean repo"
git push --force origin master
```

Comment: It is now asking me if I am sure I want to remove a write protected files, for each file and there seems to be a lot...

```rm: remove write-protected regular file '.git/objects/a2/dc6463791d402ae1aff21814cdc98ec5781174'? yes

rm: remove write-protected regular file '.git/objects/5b/1bb1e16b23f0f41280b132a34563503967fd2f'? y

rm: remove write-protected regular file '.git/objects/02/a2bbae898d0765f15c6778f3c5ac161e46e4ec'? y

rm: remove write-protected regular file '.git/objects/fb/302ac064d4bdb2f12a2a2f4ef3b50fbb13a2e2'? ```

Comment: looks like ```rm -rf .git``` worked. the ```-f``` makes it force delete which is what I needed with. Togther it is ```-rf```

Answer (score 0):

1. create 1st project
2. make git init
3. create a remote repo for 1st project
4. link remote repo to 1st project
5. create 2nd project
6. make git init
7. create a remote repo for 2nd project
8. link remote repo to 2nd project

Git will push everything to its proper remote repo

Comment: in step 6 when I use ```$ git init``` in a new directory it just says "Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/user/new_project/.git/"

Comment: yes, because git is working with one repository at a time

Answer (score 0):

Small hint from my side

git init : create empty repository and reinitialize an existing one

following link will give more information about different options can be used during git init ($GIT_DIR)
https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html

Comment: thanks, but which options to select to create empty repository? is it --bare like this: ```git init --bare```?